# Titanium mobile publish apk error message

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I have trying to publish android apk file from Titanium studio but the studio is giving me error.

```
[ERROR] Program launch failed. Unable to locate Java VM. Please set JAVA_HOME environment 
variable.
[ERROR] Unabled to prepare JavaScript for packaging. Error code 4.
```

However everything is working fine in emulator. Plus Java home variable is set and i have also tested it with HelloWorld example.

Can anyone help

Answer (score 1):

I guess you had a look at [how to set up Titanium Studio and SDK](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Setting_up_Titanium_Studio). Please ensure that your also set all the [all the environment variables](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables) especially those related to Android SDK. Finally you should check that you run the [correct versions of all required parts](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix). You need Java 6 32bit on Windows for instance.

If all this doesn't help please provide the `build.log` (in your project folder) and the results of the diagnostic test (Help -> Titanium Studio -> Run Diagnostic Test) and also provide the general log file (same menu as test).